# xamarin forms command issue

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, command

I have a strange issue
I am usin Prism on my xamarin forms app.

There is a command that navigates the user to spesific page. XAML code is the below

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Icon="add_circle_white_48dp.png" Command="{Binding NavigateToPage}" CommandParameter="Asset" />
    <ToolbarItem Text="Detay" Command="{Binding NavigateToPage}" CommandParameter="AssetTabbed" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

this NavigateToPage command work fine in here but if I want to add this command in a list view viewcell ContextActions  as below

```
                            <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                <MenuItem Text="Detay" IsDestructive="False"
                                          Command="{Binding NavigateToPage}" CommandParameter="AssetTabbed" />
                            </ViewCell.ContextActions>
```

the command is not working

Answer (score 1):

The ViewCell has a different binding context. You will need to do this:

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Button Command="{Binding BindingContext.YourCommand,Source={x:Reference page}}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>


public class YourPageViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public YourPageViewModel()
    {
        YourCommand = new DelegateCommand<MyModel>( ExecuteMyCommand );
    }

    public ObservableCollection<YourModel> Collection { get; set; }

    public DelegateCommand<YourModel> YourCommand { get; }

    private void ExecuteYourCommand( YourModel model )
    {
        // Your Logic
    }
```

Comment: this did not work. Source={x:Reference page} should be the name of ListView not page